# insert or update keys in a python dictionary

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary

I have a python dictionary `dict1` with more than 20,000 keys and I want to `update` it with another dictionary `dict2`. The dictionaries look like this:

```
dict1
  key11=>[value11]
  key12=>[value12]
  ...
  ...
  keyxyz=>[value1x]      //common key
  ...... so on

dict2
  key21=>[value21]
  key22=>[value22]
  ...
  ...
  keyxyz=>[value2x]      // common key
  ........ so on
```

If I use

```
dict1.update(dict2)
```

then the keys of `dict1` which are similar to keys of `dict2` will have their values overwritten by values of `dict2`. What I want is if a key is already present in dict1 then the value of that key in dict2 should be appended to value of dict1. So

```
dict1.conditionalUpdate(dict2)
```

should result in

```
dict1
  key11=>[value11]
  key12=>[value12]
  key21=>[value21]
  key22=>[value22]
  ...
  ...
  keyxyz=>[value1x,value2x]
```

A naive method would be iterating over keys of `dict2` for each key of `dict1` and insert or update keys. Is there a better method? Does python support a built in data structure that supports this kind of functionality?

Comment: Here is a solution to a similar question already posted.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-can-i-merge-two-python-dictionaries-as-a-single-expression

Comment: @ronyswag That is not the same question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) from the collections module.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> dict1 = {1:'a',2:'b',3:'c'}
>>> dict2 = {1:'hello', 4:'four', 5:'five'}
>>> my_dict = defaultdict(list)
>>> for k in dict1:
...    my_dict[k].append(dict1[k])
...
>>> for k in dict2:
...    my_dict[k].append(dict2[k])
...
>>> my_dict[1]
['a', 'hello']
```

Comment: Correct. In fact, if you check out the Python docs there is an example which nearly matches what you're asking for - http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples

Answer (score 3):

Another method without importing anything, just with the regular Python dictionary:

```
>>> dict1 = {1:'a',2:'b',3:'c'}
>>> dict2 = {1:'hello', 4:'four', 5:'five'}
>>> for k in dict2:
...  dict1[k] = dict1.get(k,"") + dict2.get(k)
... 
>>> dict1
{1: 'ahello', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'four', 5: 'five'}
>>>
```

`dict1.get(k,"")` returns the value associated to `k` if it exists or an empty string otherwise, and then append the content of `dict2`.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually pretty simple to do using a dict comprehension and `itertools.groupby()`:

```
dict1 = {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4}
dict2 = {5: 6, 7: 8, 1: 1, 2: 2}

from itertools import groupby, chain
from operator import itemgetter

sorted_items = sorted(chain(dict1.items(), dict2.items()))

print({key: [value[1] for value in values] for key, values in groupby(sorted_items, itemgetter(0))})
```

Gives us:

```
{1: [1, 1], 2: [2, 2], 3: [3], 4: [4], 5: [6], 7: [8]}
```

Naturally, this creates a new dict, but if you *need* to update the first dict, you can do that trivially by updating with the new one. If your values are already lists, this may need some minor modification (but I presume you were doing that for the sake of the operation, in which case, there is no need).

Naturally, if you are using Python 2.x, then you will want to use `dict.viewitems()` or `dict.iteritems()` over `dict.items()`. If you are using a version of Python prior to dict comprehensions, then you could use `dict((key , value) for ...)` instead.